# Replacing preg_replace e modifier with callback in legacy project

Tags: php, regex

I have a very old legacy project I need to get to work on php 5.6 :-(

I need to replace the use of the e modifier with preg_replace and use preg_repolace_callback instaead.

The original code with my replacements marked:

```
//REPLACED THIS     $in= '!\[\~([0-9]+)\~\]!ise';
//WITH THIS
$in= '!\[\~([0-9]+)\~\]!is'

$isfriendly= ($this->config['friendly_alias_urls'] == 1 ? 1 : 0);
$pref= $this->config['friendly_url_prefix'];
$suff= $this->config['friendly_url_suffix'];
$thealias= '$aliases[\\1]';
$found_friendlyurl= "\$this->makeFriendlyURL('$pref','$suff',$thealias)";
$not_found_friendlyurl= "\$this->makeFriendlyURL('$pref','$suff','" . '\\1' . "')";
$out= "({$isfriendly} && isset({$thealias}) ? {$found_friendlyurl} : {$not_found_friendlyurl})";

//I NEED TO REPLACE THIS $documentSource= preg_replace($in,$out, $documentSource);
//WITH WHAT?
```

I tried

```
  $documentSource= preg_replace_callback($in,create_function('$isfriendly,$thealias,$found_friendlyurl,$not_found_friendlyurl',"({$isfriendly} && isset({$thealias}) ? {$found_friendlyurl} : {$not_found_friendlyurl})"), $documentSource);
```

But that didn't work, gave an invalid callback error.

Anyone help? I Looked at other examples in SO but can't work this out because of use of complex curly brackets and general unfamiliarity with the functions involved.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to use `create_function` in modern PHP.

Comment: The `e` modifier should still work. The documentation says it was removed in 7.0.0, not 5.6. Can you show the original `preg_replace` call? I can't figure out what you're doing, because your callback function takes too many arguments. The callback function is only given one argument.

Comment: Please reformulate your domain problem into a succinct programming puzzle. You might run the risk of not having to ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing that you're mostly using properties (`$this->…`) already, it's best to define the custom callback not as anonymous function, but as method anyway:

```
public function preg_callback($matches) {

    #-- Retain the flag lookups:    
    $isfriendly = ($this->config['friendly_alias_urls'] == 1 ? 1 : 0);
    $pref = $this->config['friendly_url_prefix'];
    $suff = $this->config['friendly_url_suffix'];

    #-- Exchange `\\1` placeholder for $matches[1]
    $thealias = $aliases[$matches[1]];
               #  ↑ needs to become an property

    #-- Rearrange the odd expression salad into a proper condition:
    if ($isfriendly && isset($thealias)) {
                               # ↑ likely needs a lookup elsewhere
        # formerly `$found_friendlyurl`
        return $this->makeFriendlyURL($pref, $suff, $thealias);
    }
    else {
        # or `$not_found_friendlyurl`
        return $this->makeFriendlyURL($pref, $suff, $matches[1]);
    }                                                 # ↑ `\\1`
}
```

Note that is this **just a loose syntax example**. <sup>(I'm not going to rewrite your code completely.)</sup>

- You still have to turn `$aliases` into a property.
- Config flags get evaluated for each regex match, not just once.
- Then simply invoke it per `preg_replace_callback($rx, [$this, "preg_callback"], $src);`

The important takeaway here is, that you just undo all the tedious variable interpolating and doubly escaping, which was necessary for the inline `/eval`-mode before.